# Re using a State Machine in CAPL

Tags: state-machine, capl

I have made a very simple state machine in CAPL that tells me when a signal went high and for how long it stayed ON before turning OFF.
Now I have around 70 more signals where I need to know when the signal started and how long it stayed ON before going in OFF .
The code that I have implemented is here.

My question: Is there a way to templatize of make a function of this state machine so I dont have to implement this everywhere in the code.

```
on message x639
{
   message x639 mil_obj;
   mil_obj = this;

   switch(mil_state)
    {
      case MIL_OFF:
        {
          if(mil_obj.iHwEcm_MILInput_flg == 1)
            {
            mil_start_time = (timeNow()/100000);
            mil_state = MIL_ON;
            }
            else
            {
            mil_state = MIL_OFF;
            }

          break;
        }
      case MIL_ON:
        {
          if(mil_obj.iHwEcm_MILInput_flg == 0)
          {
            mil_stop_time = (timeNow()/100000);
            mil_retval = writeCreate("MIL_STATUS");
            writeLineEx(mil_retval,1," MIL turned ON at %ld  seconds for a duration of %ld seconds ", mil_start_time, mil_stop_time - mil_start_time);
            mil_stop_time =0;
            mil_start_time =0;
            mil_state = MIL_OFF;

          }
          else
          {
          mil_state = MIL_ON;

          }

          break;
        }
      default:

          break;     
    }

output(mil_obj);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to avoid having to copy paste your code for every signal.

You can use arrays to store the state and start_time for every signal you are interested in. It is a bit tricky to access these arrays since you do not have a construct like in a std::map where you could do

```
state["Signal1"] = STATE_ON;
```

So make a struct that stores the signal name, the state and the start_time (stop_time doesn't need to be saved in your example, because its not used after you calculate and output it). Like:

```
  struct signal_state {
    char sig_name[100];
    int last_value;
    int start_time;
  };
```

Then make a large array of these states (so every signal fits in)

Everytime you want to access the state of a signal you have to iterate through the array and `strcmp()` all the values with the signal you want to access to get the correct index of the array. That can take a lot of time for very large arrays, but for your 70 signals it should compute in almost no time.

The following code should be very close to what you actually want:

```
/*@!Encoding:1252*/
includes
{

}

variables
{
  const max_sig_name_len = 100;
  const max_num_states = 100;

  struct signal_state {
    char sig_name[max_sig_name_len];
    int last_value;
    int start_time;
  };

  int num_states = 0;
  struct signal_state states[max_num_states];

}

on start {
  register_signal("CAN1::net1::Message1::Signal1");
  register_signal("CAN1::net1::Message2::Signal2");
}

on signal Signal1 {
  handle_signal(this.name, this.raw);
  output(this);
}

on signal Signal2 {
  handle_signal(this.name, this.raw);
  output(this);
}

void register_signal(char foo[]) {
  strncpy(states[num_states].sig_name, foo, max_sig_name_len);
  num_states++;
}

void handle_signal(char sig_name[], int sig_value) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_states; i++) {
    if (strncmp(sig_name, states[i].sig_name, max_sig_name_len) == 0) 
      break;
    //writeLineEx(0,1, "%s != %s", this.name, states[i].sig_name);
  }
  // i now contains the index of the state that represents the current signal
  if (i < num_states) {
    if ( sig_value == 0 && states[i].last_value > 0) {
      int stop_time;
      stop_time = timeNow()/100000;
      writeLineEx(0,1, "signal %s turned ON at %ld seconds for a duration of %ld seconds.", states[i].sig_name, states[i].start_time, stop_time - states[i].start_time );
    } else if (sig_value > 0 && states[i].last_value == 0) {
      states[i].start_time = timeNow()/100000;
    }
    states[i].last_value = sig_value;
  }
}
```

`register_signal()` is just a convenient way to fill your array. 
`handle_signal()` will have to be called in the `on signal` handlers of the signals you are interested in.

Comment: If you have troubles with my code, feel free to ask. If this or Dmitrys answer helps you, please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1.Enumerate all signals, (and also signals states) and list their names:

```c
 variables
 {
   enum signalName {
    signal1,
    signal2,
    ...
    signal639,
    ...
    signal70,
    signalMax
  };
  char signalName[signalMax][64] {
    "name_of_signal1",
    "name_of_signal2",
    ...
    "MIL", // name of the signal from message x639
    ...
    "name_of_signal70"
  };
  enum signalState {
    SIG_OFF,
    SIG_ON
  };
}
```

2.Put your code which calculates the delay in a function. I basically took your code and generalized the `mil_state` and `mil_start_time` variables.

```c
void CalculateHoldTime(enum signalId id, signal s) {
  int signal_state[signalMax];
  dword signal_start_time[signalMax];
  dword stop_time;
  dword retval;

   switch(signal_state[id])
    {
      case SIG_OFF:
          if(s == 1) {
              signal_start_time[id] = (timeNow()/100000);
              signal_state[id] = SIG_ON;
          }
          else signal_state[id] = SIG_OFF;
          break;
      case SIG_ON:
          if(s == 0) {
            stop_time = (timeNow()/100000);
            retval = writeCreate("SIG_STATUS"); // or signalName[id] if you need one tab per signal
            writeLineEx(retval,1," Signal %s turned ON at %ld  seconds for a duration of %ld seconds ", signalName[id], signal_start_time[id], stop_time - signal_start_time[id]);
            signal_start_time[id] =0;
            signal_state[id] = SIG_OFF;
          }
          else signal_state[id] = SIG_ON;
          break;
      default:
          break;     
    }
}
```

3.Call this function from your message handlers. You will have to repeat this code for each message you receive, but it's considerably smaller.

```c
on message x639
{
  message x639 mil_obj;
  mil_obj = this;
  CalculateHoldTime(signal639, mil_obj.iHwEcm_MILInput_flg);
  output(mil_obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In step 2 , in  the Calculate Hold Function you have declared the second parameter as a "state", But in step 3 when you are calling the function you are actually passing a "signal".Please correct me if I misunderstood. Thanks again.

Comment: You're right, that's an error. Basically, you need the second parameter to match the type of `mil_obj.iHwEcm_MILInput_flg`. I will assume it's `signal`.

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you explain why is there a need for enum signal name. Please explain the significance.

Comment: Also please explain where is the "enum signalId id" that you are passing in the function. Thanks again sir.